# Mousewheel function doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll, mousewheel

I made a function that increment a class on a `li` list on mousewheel, it's working perfectly on chrome and safari but doesn't on Firefox, how can i fix it ? 
There is my code:

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0,
  allowTransition = true;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {

  if (allowTransition) {
    allowTransition=false;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        count--
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (scrollable > count) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        count++
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      allowTransition=true;
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }

ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) instead of `mousewheel`? What *does* happen in Firefox? Any errors in the dev console?

Comment: yes is that thank you :)

Comment: but always on firefox now the browser is scrolling only down, cant back up